# Counting sequences of increasing numbers that may be equal

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of sequences $(a_1,a_2,\dots ,a_k)$ of length $k$ such that $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$ are in the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $a_1\le a_2 \le \dots \le a_k$?

I have worked on this problem a few hours and I need some tips. I simply can't continue losing time on it and I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: I reformatted the formulas. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Using JimmyK4542's hint, you just need to count the number of ways to select k cookies from n types of cookies, and you can do this using what many MSE users call "stars and bars": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Once you fix the number of $1$'s, $2$'s, ..., $n$'s that are in the sequence, there is only one distinct way to arrange them in increasing order. So, how many ways can we pick the number of $1$'s, $2$'s, ..., $n$'s such that we pick a total of $k$ numbers? This is a balls and urns type problem.

Answer (score 2):

The approach in the above answer is the easiest, but another way to do this is to define

$\;\;\;\;b_i=a_{i}+i-1$ for $1\le i\le k$.

Given a sequence $(a_1,\cdots,a_k)$ with $a_1\le a_2\le\cdots\le a_k$ and $a_i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ for each $i$,  this gives a sequence $(b_1,\cdots,b_k)$ with $b_1< b_2<\cdots< b_k$ and $b_i\in\{1,\cdots,n+k-1\}$ for each $i$.

Since any such sequence $(b_1,\cdots,b_k)$ gives a sequence $(a_1,\cdots,a_k)$ satisfying the given conditions using $\;\;\;a_i=b_{i}-i+1$,
there is a 1-1 correspondence between the two types of sequences.

Since the number of sequences $(b_1,\cdots,b_k)$ with $b_1< b_2<\cdots< b_k$ and $b_i\in\{1,\cdots,n+k-1\}$ for each $i$ is just the number of ways to select $k$ numbers from $n+k-1$ numbers, or $\displaystyle\binom{n+k-1}{k}$,

this gives the number of sequences

$(a_1,\cdots,a_k)$ with $a_1\le a_2\le\cdots\le a_k$ and $a_i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ for each $i$ as well.